# Sum of projective submodules of a projective over a semihereditary ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, projective-modules

Sorry in advance if this is too silly. Let $R$ be a right semihereditary ring and $P$ a projective right $R$-module. It is well-known that finitely generated (thus projective) submodules of $P$ form a lattice. Let now $F$ be a finitely generated submodule of $P$ and $S$ a (possibly infinitely generated) projective submodule of $P$. Is $F+S \subseteq P$ also necessarily projective? <strike>I'm mainly interested in the case of $R$ being noetherian, when $F \cap S$ is f.g. and thus projective (so in this case we know at least that $F+S$ has projective dimension $\leq 1$).</strike>

I would suspect that this is false, but I'm unable to create a counterexample. Thanks for any input.

Comment: You say you're mainly interested in the case where $R$ is noetherian. But a noetherian semihereditary ring is hereditary, so $F+S$ is projective because **every** submodule of $P$ is projective.

Comment: I see that my in-advance apology has not come in vain, this was indeed silly. Thank you for the comment. However, I would still be interested in the non-noetherian setting.

Comment: What is an example of a semi hereditary non-hereditary ring?

Comment: For example an infinite product of fields.